# sort data frame using panda

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have an excel sheet with data already inserted.
I retrieve the data into data frame using:

```
df= pd.read_excel('myfile.XLSX')
```

and its works.

I want to sort the data by specific column so i use the command:

```
df.sort_values(by=['column name'],na_position='last')
```

with no success.

When the program exceuted im opening the excel sheet and there is no change in the data.

What could be the issue? The column name is correct, I grab the command from `pandas.doc` so I'm really dont know why is notworking.

Hope someone can help, thanks.

- dataframe example :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJNmF.png)

the result supposed to be- [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ClAf.png)

Comment: Please post your dataframe, error and expected output

Comment: Do you save the dataframe as a new excel sheet after you sort...?

Comment: `sort_values` does not work in place, either do `sort_values(…, inplace=True)` or `df = df.sort_values(…)`

Comment: the dataframe include 18 columns and 63 rows.

Comment: is your goal to sort it by value? ``df = df.sort_values('column name', ascending=False)`` and dont forget ``df.to_excel('directory')``

Comment: i figure something very weird that happened, df= pd.read_excel('TEST.XLSX')
when i use print im getting all data
   dataframe = df.sort_values(by=['Planned Task'],inplace=True,na_position='last')
   print(dataframe) here im getting none

Comment: i tried your suggestion but not working @mozway

Comment: @ohadHa please provide an example dataset where it fails and also provide the expected output. Understand that we cannot help you further without seeing example data

Comment: @tomerPoliakov yes i want to sort by value,  df.to_excel gave me AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Comment: @ mozway i edit in the post example. there is no errors

Answer (score 0):

the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_excel` means that your'e trying to perform an action on a variable that's `== None`, make sure that you assign the variable to the dataframe correctly:

```
df = pt.read_excel(directory)
df = df.sort_values('column name', ascending=False)
df.to_excel(directory)
```

Comment: yes, figure it. but still cant understand why? im doing   df= pd.read_excel('TEST.xlsx')
here im getting all the data in the excel i checked that.
   df = df.sort_values(by=['column name'],inplace=True,na_position='last')  
   df.to_excel('directory')